# Alter JSON file in CLOUD SHELL Terminal

Tags: json, command-line-interface, google-cloud-vertex-ai

this is my file :

```
$ cat INPUT-JSON
{"endpointId": "1411183591831896064", "instance": "[{age: 40.77430558, ClientID: '997', income: 44964.0106, loan: 3944.219318}]"}
```

I want to alter it to :

```
$ cat INPUT-JSON
{"endpointId": "1411183591831896064", "instance": "[{age: 30.00, ClientID: '998', income: 50000.00, loan: 20000.00}]"}
```

How do I do that using CLOUD SHELL Terminal ? (on google cloud platform)

(this is part of a Qwiklab : Vertex AI: Predicting Loan Risk with AutoML from https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/course_templates/3?hl=es_419&locale=fr_CA&skip_cache=true&utm_campaign=cgc&utm_medium=website&utm_source=gcp_training )

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Since you're just editing the values in the json file, you can try `vim` editor to edit your file.

Comment: I tried but apparently I don't have yet 15 in reputation. "But my [positve] feedback was recorded"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just editing the values in the json file, you can use the `vim` [editor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getting-started-with-vim-editor-in-linux/) or `vi` [editor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vi-editor-unix/) to edit your file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Google Cloud Terminal. To edit/alter those values:

1. Click on "Open Editor" above your terminal in the top right corner.
2. Then you modify the values via the JSON File.
3. When finished click on "Open Terminal", then rerun your last script to notice the different outcome.

Hope this helps!